# How to split a string multiple times in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a text file, each line is a string.

The most extreme could look like this:

```
A01B01C01D100E500F100.00G100.00H100.00
```

**A little information about possibilities:**

- Each string will include at least one of those letters and a number
- the numbers following the letters can be any number of digits and places past the decimal.
- The letters are not always in order

**Another example of the data:**

```
A01B400C62.578D77.297
C62.409D77.222
C62.259D77.113
C62.135D76.975
C62.042D76.815
C61.985D76.638
C61.973D76.529
A03B10000
A0C62.760 D77.336
A0E3.000
A01F400E0
A01B400E-0.100
```

What I would like to do is split the string at each letter, and taking all of the numbers until the next letter. With results like so:

```
A01, B01, C01, D100, E500, F100.00, G100.00, H100.00
```

I have tried a bunch of things, and the closest I have gotten is this

```
dicedLine = myLine.split(/[ABCDEFGH]/)
```

This gives me CLOSE to what I want, except I have found that if you have a string that does not include one of those letters in the search, then the results are not what I am after.

For example a line like this:

```
A30
```

Will give me results like this:

```
["", "30"]
```

Where I would really want results like this:

```
["A30", "",  "",  "", "", "", "", ""]
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Shall `"D62.409C77.222"` result in `["", "", "C77.222", "D62.409", "", "", "", ""]`? Can you be more specific?

Comment: once the string is split, the order doesn't matter so much. I'm planning to do results.indexOf('X') to manipulate the data as needed.

Comment: But you still want results like `["A30", "",  "",  "", "", "", "", ""]` instead of `["A30"]` or even `Set ["A30"]`?

Comment: exactly. I want the full 'set' for each string given. Even if the set is only one actual value and 7 blanks.

This is basically just cleaning up the data so I can pass it to another function and parse out what I need.

Comment: I don't get it. You want to perform indexOf on the results - so I assume the index is important to you. But then you say the order doesn't matter - so I assume you would be equally happy with a `Set`. But then you say you also want the blanks - which doesn't make sense if you are not interested in the indices...

Comment: Sorry for the vague answer - I was trying to make it easy and say 'as long as I have the whole set, I can proceed' regardless of the order.

But YES - having the entire set (blanks included), in the same order *everytime* would the perfect result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that a particular character exists, without actually consuming it:

```js
codes = [
  "A01B400C62.578D77.297",
  "C62.409D77.222",
  "C62.259D77.113",
  "C62.135D76.975",
  "C62.042D76.815",
  "C61.985D76.638",
  "C61.973D76.529",
  "A03B10000",
  "A0C62.760 D77.336",
  "A0E3.000",
  "A01F400E0",
  "A01B400E-0.100",
];

console.log(codes.map(code => code.split(/ *(?=[A-Z])/)));
```

Note I also added  `*` to remove the spaces, if any.

Comment: That was the regex I was looking for. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> Where I would really want results like this:
>
> `["A30", "",  "",  "", "", "", "", ""]`

If the letters are ordered, this is easily accomplished by capturing each letter + digits in its own group as follows:

```js
let re = /(A[^A-Z]+)?(B[^A-Z]+)?(C[^A-Z]+)?(D[^A-Z]+)?(E[^A-Z]+)?(F[^A-Z]+)?(G[^A-Z]+)?(H[^A-Z]+)?/;

console.log(re.exec("A01B01C01D100E500F100.00G100.00H100.00").slice(1));
console.log(re.exec("C30").slice(1));
```

Non-matching groups produce an `undefined` array entry. Those can easily be mapped to empty strings if desired.

> The letters are not always in order

You would need to replace the individual letters in the given regexp with their generic group `[A-Z]`.

However, your question is ambiguous about unordered letters. Shall `"C30B30"` result in `["", "B30",  "C30",  "", "", "", "", ""]`? Or `["B30", "C30",  "",  "", "", "", "", ""]`? We can't answer that part of the question without more specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easily with *match* rather than *split*. It's a simper regular expression so likely more compatible. Just beware that if no matches are found, it returns *null* rather than an empty array.

```js
var data = [
 'A01B400C62.578D77.297',
 'C62.409D77.222',
 'C62.259D77.113',
 'C62.135D76.975',
 'C62.042D76.815',
 'C61.985D76.638',
 'C61.973D76.529',
 'A03B10000',
 'A0C62.760 D77.336',
 'A0E3.000',
 'A01F400E0',
 'A01B400E-0.100'
];

var result = data.map(s => s.match(/[a-z][^a-z]+/gi));

console.log(result);
```